# Preventing out of memory error in Netty 4.0.0.Alpha

Tags: netty

I am develop a server application to streaming data to clients by using Netty. Basically, there is a main server feeding data to my application and the application will distributed the data to registered users. As my application need to be maintained in very long term and Netty 3.5.8 and Netty 4.0.0 are quite different in term of API so I decide to go with Netty 4.0.0

However, I run into the problem that when the main server feed too much data which cannot be distributed to clients fast enough. Heap memory usage increase and causes out of memory so I try to do something to check buffer of the client before write data in order to prevent this problem. I use discard example in the website (http://static.netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/discard/package-summary.html) but it doesn't work because, sometimes, heap memory is full before the listener is called. I look this example in Netty 3.5.8 and found that the example check actual buffer before write data. It is different from example in 4.0.0 Therefore, do we have a way to check buffer before write it down in netty 4.0.0??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The way I handled this is:

1. When the server writes the data, the call which writes 64k'th byte is called synchronously. So the call gets blocked until the data is consumed by the other end.
2. The other end does not consume the data until the data it has already consumed is processed and discarded.

Follow the same pattern throughout. It may slow things down a bit but will prevent out of memory error. Slowness should not be of concern since if it's of concern you already have a use case in your application architecture (outside of netty) which needs addressing.